# Should I combine my cookies into one or having multiple ones does not change anything with performance

Tags: wordpress, performance, cookies

I have a blog with WordPress and I am using a plugin for the ratings of my posts.

Every time a reader rates an article it creates a cookie just for that article. And every time a reader loads a new page it loads all the cookies for each article he/she rated.

Here is a screenshot of what a reader sees inside his Inspect Element:

[image]

Should I modify the plugin and put all this information into one or will it not change anything with the performance of the blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion would be, yes, combine them into one cookie. However, cookies have a length limit of about 4k, so if the user reviews a ton of articles you will run into issues with storage. With this approach, you could try segmenting the cookie into multiple compiled cookies, but then you run into issues with checking lengths and end up with a bunch of random code.

What I would do in this situation is assign a user ID to the person and attach that ID to a server-side tracking mechanism. Instead of creating a cookie for each rating, you simply create one cookie (I would recommend [PHP sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)). Then attach each review with the ID and the rating as `post_meta` for the article. Then the cookie would always be the same length, and it would tie the user back to the reviews that they completed. This also allows you to group your reviews together by a single identifier, which would allow you to transfer the reviews to, say, a user account.